# data lost in cassandra 1.1.2

Tags: java, cassandra, hector

I'm writing a Java program, using Hector to interface with cassandra.  I find that after running a batch process to import data, I can read the newly written rows using both my Java client and the cassandra-cli program.  However, after restarting the server, the data disappears.

Some other interesting information... I built a large database on my home machine (windows) initially, using an older version of cassandra (0.8), then transferred the data to my current production machine.  I find that the old data stays around after a server restart.  I also find that smaller databases seem to be updating fine, I don't see any data loss there after a server restart.

I have tried upgrading to the latest version of cassandra (1.1.2), and moving back to Java 6_33 to run the server (from 7_4).  Nothing works.  Please help!

Comment: After importing data and before restart try "nodetool flush" and see if the data is there or not. This is not the solution but the way you can find out cause of the issue

Comment: did you by any chance that has the column ttl set?

Comment: How many nodes do you have in your production cluster, and what is your RF, and what consistency level are you reading/writing?

Comment: @rs_atl: single node, so I guess RF and consistency levels shouldn't matter?  In any event, I haven't changed these from the defaults.

Comment: @Jasonw: I guess ttl = time to live?  I didn't even know about this feature so I'm fairly confident I'm not using it.

Comment: @samarth: imported data and ran "nodetool flush", which finished after just a few seconds.  Data is still present in both my application and with a direct query from the cassandra-cli tool.  I see about 16 CommitLog files still present though...  what now?

Comment: Well, first of all, a 1 node Cassandra "cluster" is an anti-pattern.  3 nodes would be minimum reasonable cluster size.  Regarding the data, is all of it (your old and new data) in a single CF, or is the old data isolated to an old CF you don't need anymore?

Comment: There are many good reasons to use Cassandra, even if you don't need its clustering feature.  I use it because I have 50 million rows with 100,000 sparse dynamic columns in my schema design.  nosql excels in such situations.

Answer (score 1):

This may have been caused by failing to run the "nodetool upgradesstables" command when migrating from 0.8 to a newer version of cassandra.  Note the NEWS.txt file in the cassandra download which gives tips about the upgrade process.

edit: confirmed, this was the problem.  Thanks to those that helped!

Answer (score 0):

Commitlogs are not properly flushed in cassandra versions 1.1.0 to 1.1.4 This is a open issue. Please refer the following jira ticket.

[Commitlog not replayed after restart](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4782)